# Entity framework code first - What is the best approch to set property when entity is saved

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 and using the code first approch.

This is my class

```
public class Dummy {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastModifiyed { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is that everytime the Dummy object is saved the lastModifiyed property should be set to the current time.

Even if I'm using attribute like requried this code will still be valid.

```
var d = new Dummy();
d.lastModifiyed = DateTime.MinValue
```

What is the best practies to do this kind of stuff. I have read that override the SaveChanges in the class that Inherits from DbContext and check for example a interface is a good way to go. Or how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `SaveChanges` method and before calling `base.SaveChanges` enumerate changes from change tracker. I.e:

```
foreach (var item in (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Deleted)
    .Where(entry => entry.Entity is ITracksLastModified)
    .Select(entry => entry.Entity as ITracksLastModified))
{
    item.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```